# elasticsearch | template query | java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I was trying to implement the feature of template query. Refer to the last section of http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html

I added a query template using sense. Now the need is through JAVA API of elasticsearch, I need to execute this query template and store the result in SearchResponse. However I am not able to find any API related to query Template. The only class file which is available is TemplateQueryBuilder. This class constructs the template query perfectly but I am not sure of which method to be called from Client in order to pass the object of TemplateQueryBuilder.
Help in this is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to do it :

```
SearchRequestBuilder request = client;.prepareSearch();
request.setTemplateName(templateName);
request.setTemplateType(ScriptService.ScriptType.INDEXED);
request.setTemplateParams(templateParams);
SearchResponse response = request.get();
```

You just need to parse the response object then ..

refer to: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/search.html#java-search-template

Answer (score 1):

Note that with API version 2.X, as `request.setTemplateX` methods are deprecated, you should use a different approach.
Either you can use `request.setTemplate(Template template)` which is similar to the accepted answer, or you can go with the more generic `QueryBuilders` approach:

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.templateQuery(
    "templateName",
    ScriptService.ScriptType.FILE,
    templateParams);
```

More to read: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/2.4/java-specialized-queries.html#java-query-dsl-template-query